# CSS Display and Float Properties

Tags: html, css

Will the display property of an inline element change once a float property is applied? e.g. What will be the the display property of an anchor tag with float:left?

Also, what will happen with its parent display property, will it also change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the display property of an inline
>   element change once a float property
>   is applied? e.g. What will be the the
>   display property of an anchor tag with
>   float:left?

The `display` property will be unchanged. If by ‘anchor tag’ you mean ‘`A` element’, then the `display` property would still be set to `inline` (by default).

> Also, what will happen with its parent
>   display property, will it also change?

The `display` property of the parent element will remain the same as well.

Comment: So is it allowed to float inline elements? If you say so, then is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

remember, though, that if you apply background/border stylings, the content will be floated out of the container, causing a 0-height box.

Answer (score 0):

The Float property will not affect the Display property.

An anchor tag with float:left will probably have the display property as 'inline'.

Guess the float:left caused your anchor to move 'behind' one of your other elements on the left...

Try a higher z-index..

Comment: `float` will take it out of normal flow, not affect `display`.